# Responsive navigation DIV with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to have a DIV around my main navigation, which contains my navigation, its size will be fixed based on the

.. e.g. 600 px, what I want is if the screen resolution is small than the size of navigation, it will add Arrows on left and right so once clicked it will scroll and show the hidden navigation buttons, please check the screenshot to make it more clear..

my question is, is there any jquery plugin that does something similar, if so it will save me a lot of time, OR where should I get started, any direction would be highly appreciated..[image]

Comment: use width defined as `width:70%` it will be responsive

Comment: Almost all responsive sites stack the menu so that user gets to see all the menu even if the screen shrinks.

Comment: Thanks for the input AJ, sometimes, you have different design requirements.. regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be to hard. Take a look at this plugin: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/
It's a responsive carousel and when you look around at the demo-section, you will see that what you want is possible with the carousel.